# Keycloak, Generating a JWT token by admin api for a specific user

Tags: keycloak

In keycloak, I want to generate a JWT token for a specified by Admin's Api (Just by user's id, without password). And send it back to the user
How can I do that?
I've looked in keycloak api page, but I couldn't find anything useful. :(

Thanks

Comment: You want to get a token without having to pass the user's password again is that it? Could you rephrase the question to be a bit more clear

Comment: Yes, I wan to generate an access token for a specified user at the back_end-side.
Actually, I want to implement a forget password for my self (without keycloak ui). How can I do that?